# DrRacket seg fault

Tags: raspbian, apt

I'm trying to install [racket](http://racket-lang.org/) on my RaspBerry Pi.
I've installed racket via

```
sudo apt-get install racket
```

When I enter 'racket', it runs just fine. But when I run 'drracket' or 'sudo drracket', it returns a seg fault:

```
Seg fault (internal error) at -address-
SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR SI_CODE 2 fault on -address-
Aborted
```

Anyone know what's the cause of this or how I can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest version from the website (as of this writing it is 6.1)

http://download.racket-lang.org/

and compile it from source.

```
tar zxvf racket-6.1-src-builtpkgs.tgz
cd racket-6.1/src
./configure
make
make install
```

Working for me on a ARMHF laptop.

Comment: This does work on my Rasp Pi B+, it takes about an hour to build. DrRacket takes a few minutes to start, and then runs very slowly, e.g. a single expression in the definitions panel takes about 5 seconds to run. I imagine that it's possible to speed things up by turning off some options.

Comment: Update on my previous comment -- On my Rasp Pi 2 Model B, DrRacket runs much more quickly and is pretty usable.

Answer (score 1):

The current version doesn't work on ARMv6 (see: [Raspberry Pi • Which Language to Learn?](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=38971&p=457133)) and there are [efforts](https://github.com/rm-hull/raspberry-racket) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried myself, but more recent versions of Racket should have support for ARM6 and even have JIT support on ARM. You can get a pre-release build of Racket that's already built for Raspbian here (look for "ARM6 VFP, built on Raspbian" under "Linux"): http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/

Comment: DrRacket in the current version from this link doesn't work on my Rasp Pi Model B+, it exits with a fatal error.

Comment: Can you post to the Racket mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users) with the error that you get?